# Unable to deploy a report folder with ant

Tags: reporting, deployment, ant, deployment-api, deployment-error

Hello,

I try to deploy a report folder (not reports inside because sharing is modified) by using Ant but I get an error message:

> Error parsing file: Element
> {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}folderShares invalid at this
> location in type Report

I am able to retrieve the metadata but not to deploy it.
I am not sure to understand because it is the same metadata.
I understand that the folderShare shouldn't be at that place but it is what I retrieved from another organization.

This is my package file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Boutique5thAvenue</members>
        <name>Report</name>
    </types>
    <version>55.0</version>
</Package>
```

What is it wrong please?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

We can't only deploy a report folder with Ant, we need to deploy a report folder and a report related to the report folder.

Second option, we can use SFDX and in taht case, we can only deploy a report folder.